# Android - collapse notification actions by default

Tags: android, notifications

I have a notification that contains an action like this:

[image]

The action is always shown, I'd like to hide it by default so the user has to press the button at the top right to show the action so that the notification occupies less space.

I've read about using a low notification priority by calling `setPriority` on the `NotificationCompat.Builder` before posting the ongoing notification from my foreground service, but this doesn't seem to work. I'm using Android SDK version 28.

Comment: please share how do you set the priority

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/55757603/10778405

Comment: @Zain I've edited my question, by calling `setPriority` on the `NotificationCompat.Builder` before posting the ongoing notification from my foreground service

Answer (score 3):

Starting from API 26, using [`PRIORITY_LOW`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification#PRIORITY_LOW) is deprecated, instead you can use [`IMPORTANCE_LOW`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#IMPORTANCE_LOW) when you create the channel

```
NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, 
                                  CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
```

Also keep the low priority in the `NotificationCompat.Builder` with  `builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)`

Comment: Thanks, but that also doesn't seem to work. And yes I reinstalled the application so that the notification channel is recreated. I also tried IMPORTANCE_MIN which even hides the icon from the status bar (which is not what I want) but the action is still shown... :(

Comment: Please try this on multiple devices and different vendors.. Some device models like Xiaomi has their own settings for showing notifications

Comment: It behaves the same way in the emulator, and I tried a few different Android versions. The action does seem to get hidden when there are other notifications, whether or not I use a low importance on my notification. But I want to always hide it...

Comment: If your notification is on top of all other notifications, the action will always be shown by default. I just tested this out and came across that you still have to use `builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)` along with keeping `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW` in your channel .. and now the action is gone for me .. wish this helps you